# Echo in voice to the caller while receiver with headphone hving wire replace

Tags: wire, electrical, headphones, replacement, cellular

Hi I just replaced the old wire in my headphone with new one.But while using headphone the caller hears the voices with his own echo but while me having headphone on has no issue of echo can speaks with clear voice with no issues.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that somehow your "replacement of wire" has caused a situation where the received signal is partly being sent back or being coupled onto your microphone circuit.

Possibly both receiver and microphone wires are running adjacent without any shielding. At the least you should use twisted pair for these wires.

If you pay attention to this aspect, you should be able to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your headphones have nothing to do with hearing an echo.

All [POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) phone connections have some amount of delay.  Delays come from a number of sources.  Long hauls, [TDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-division_multiplexing) switches and Satellite Links to name a few.  Left uncompensated, both parties will hear echos as they hear their own voice at the near end and a repeat of their voice from the far end along with the other party's voice.

To remedy this, a technique called [Echo Suppression or Echo Cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_suppression_and_cancellation) is used at each end of the connected POTS phones.  Should this equipment fail at one end of the connection, the person at that end will likely hear an echo when they speak but no echo when the other person at the far end speaks.  As for the person at the far end, if that person's Echo Suppression equipment is working, they hear no echos.

Should this occur, workarounds include dropping the call and re-establishing it again.  Chances are that you will not be using the exact same phone company equipment on every call and different working Echo Suppression equipment may be used on the subsequent call.